# Magento 2: require.js error when disabling wishlist module

Tags: magento2, module, wishlist

When I disable module `Magento_Wishlist` in admin (`Stores->configuration->advanced->advanced`) I get the following error in frontend (js console):

> Uncaught Error: Script error for: addToWishlist

I cannot disable the module from CLI because of its dependencies. What can I do to get rid off the error?

I already cleaned cache, did `setup:upgrade` and `setup:static-content:deploy`

Answer (score 2):

`php bin/magento module:disable -f Magento_Wishlist` to disable a module on which other modules rely on.

It has to be done first in test environment so that any break in functionality is noticed. If your stuff breaks then the only solution is to remove the blocks in xml or phtml.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue may be its default issue,
 I have solved using xml file,
You have to enable wishlist module and go to your theme default.xml file and add `<referenceBlock name="wishlist_sidebar" remove="true" />`

Go to theme,

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addto.phtml
```

comment below code manually,

```
<div class="product-addto-links" data-role="add-to-links">
    <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->isAllow()) : ?>
        <a href="#"
            class="action towishlist"
            data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_wishlistSubmitParams; ?>'
            data-action="add-to-wishlist"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Wish List') ?></span></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <a href="#" data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($_product);?>'
        data-role="add-to-links"
        class="action tocompare"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Compare') ?></span></a>
</div>
```

Your error are gone now.

Comment: That would work, but I'm looking for a solution to disable and enable that module without commenting code - to be able to do it in the future just running a cli command or changing config in admin